When compiling kernel the "Debian way", how do I add a local version modifier?
I've been experimenting with compiling my own kernel, and I'm having difficulty adding a local version modifier when following the instructions from BuildYourOwnKernel. This is the "Debian way" of compiling a kernel using fakefoot debian/rules binary-generic instead of compiling from mainline using make bindeb-pkg.
When following the instructions, I'm actually successful compiling the kernel. However, the +test1 suffix I added as a local version modifier is only added to the .deb archive file and not on any of the binary packages. As a result, I have a conflict during installation, because the name matches the currently installed kernel.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 Server.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Current kernel:
$ uname -r
5.15.0-113-generic


Here are the steps I've followed:
1. Install dependencies
sudo apt build-dep linux linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install fakeroot crash kexec-tools kernel-wedge libncurses5 libncurses5-dev binutils-dev

2. Download source
apt source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)

3. Change into source directory
cd linux-5.15.0

4. Modify debian.master/changelog
Per the instructions:

In order to make your kernel "newer" than the stock Ubuntu kernel from
which you are based, you should add a local version modifier. Add
something like "+test1" to the end of the first version number in the
debian.master/changelog file, before building.

Therefore, I've added +test1 to the end of the first version number as follows:
$ head -n1 debian.master/changelog
linux (5.15.0-113.123+test1) jammy; urgency=medium

5. Build kernel
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic


After compiling, you'll see that the +test1 suffix has been added to all .deb files:
$ tree -L 1 /home/mike
/home/mike
├── linux-5.15.0
├── linux_5.15.0-113.123.diff.gz
├── linux_5.15.0-113.123.dsc
├── linux_5.15.0.orig.tar.gz
├── linux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
├── linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
├── linux-headers-5.15.0-113_5.15.0-113.123+test1_all.deb
├── linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
├── linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
├── linux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
├── linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
├── linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
└── linux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb

The problem, however, is the +test1 suffix has not been added to any files within the .deb file, and as a result, there's a conflict when installing the kernel.
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb 
dpkg: regarding linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb containing linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic conflicts with linux-image-5.15.0-113-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-113-generic (version 5.15.0-113.123) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb

The headers, however, are installed:
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 138403 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic (5.15.0-113.123+test1) over (5.15.0-113.123+test1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic (5.15.0-113.123+test1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-113-generic
   ...done.

But take notice that no directory includes the local version suffix +test. It appears that it simply overwrites the existing headers.
$ tree -L 1 /usr/src
/usr/src
├── linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
└── python3.10

Here is a snip of the contents of linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb:
$ dpkg -c linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb | head -n20
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./lib/modules/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./lib/modules/5.15.0-113-generic/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:31 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:31 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:31 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:31 ./usr/share/doc/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/
-rw-r--r-- root/root    714273 2024-07-07 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1292 2024-07-07 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/copyright
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/
-rw-r--r-- root/root    261963 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/.config
-rw-r--r-- root/root        39 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/.gitignore
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1013 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/.missing-syscalls.d
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1818060 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/Module.symvers
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/arch/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/arch/x86/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/arch/x86/entry/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/

Here is the contents of linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb:
$ dpkg -c linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:26 ./boot/
-rw------- root/root  11680480 2024-07-07 16:26 ./boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-113-generic
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:29 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/lib/linux/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:27 ./usr/lib/linux/triggers/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:29 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:29 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2024-07-07 16:29 ./usr/share/doc/linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic/
-rw-r--r-- root/root    714273 2024-07-07 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1292 2024-07-07 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic/copyright

Here is some tail output at the end of the build process. Take note of lines that indicate building package where the package does not contain +test1 yet the .deb does.
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdocs -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_compress -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_fixperms -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic -X/boot/
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic 
dh_installdeb -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdebconf -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic
flock -w 60 /home/mike/linux-5.15.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic -- -Vlinux:rprovides='spl-modules,  spl-dkms,  zfs-modules,  zfs-dkms,  v4l2loopback-modules,  v4l2loopback-dkms, ' 
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Depends field of package linux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic: substitution variable ${shlibs:Depends} used, but is not defined
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Built-Using field of package linux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic: substitution variable ${linux:BuiltUsing} used, but is not defined
dh_md5sums -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_builddeb -plinux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.
if [ -f debian.master/control.d/generic.inclusion-list ] ; then \
                dh_installchangelogs -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic; \
dh_installdocs -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic; \
dh_compress -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic; \
dh_fixperms -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic -X/boot/; \
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic ; \
dh_installdeb -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic; \
dh_installdebconf -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic; \
flock -w 60 /home/mike/linux-5.15.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic -- -Vlinux:rprovides='spl-modules,  spl-dkms,  zfs-modules,  zfs-dkms,  v4l2loopback-modules,  v4l2loopback-dkms, ' ; \
dh_md5sums -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic; \
dh_builddeb -plinux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic; \
fi
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Depends field of package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic: substitution variable ${shlibs:Depends} used, but is not defined
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdocs -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_compress -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_fixperms -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic -X/boot/
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic 
dh_installdeb -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdebconf -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic
flock -w 60 /home/mike/linux-5.15.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic -- -Vlinux:rprovides='spl-modules,  spl-dkms,  zfs-modules,  zfs-dkms,  v4l2loopback-modules,  v4l2loopback-dkms, ' 
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Built-Using field of package linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic: substitution variable ${linux:BuiltUsing} used, but is not defined
dh_md5sums -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_builddeb -plinux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic; 
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdocs -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_compress -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_fixperms -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic -X/boot/
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic 
dh_installdeb -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdebconf -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic
flock -w 60 /home/mike/linux-5.15.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic -- -Vlinux:rprovides='spl-modules,  spl-dkms,  zfs-modules,  zfs-dkms,  v4l2loopback-modules,  v4l2loopback-dkms, ' 
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Depends field of package linux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic: substitution variable ${shlibs:Depends} used, but is not defined
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Built-Using field of package linux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic: substitution variable ${linux:BuiltUsing} used, but is not defined
dh_md5sums -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_builddeb -plinux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-buildinfo-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdocs -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_compress -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_fixperms -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic -X/boot/
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic 
dh_installdeb -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdebconf -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
flock -w 60 /home/mike/linux-5.15.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic -- -Vlinux:rprovides='spl-modules,  spl-dkms,  zfs-modules,  zfs-dkms,  v4l2loopback-modules,  v4l2loopback-dkms, ' 
dh_md5sums -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_builddeb -plinux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdocs -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_compress -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_fixperms -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic -X/boot/
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic 
dh_installdeb -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdebconf -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
flock -w 60 /home/mike/linux-5.15.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic -- -Vlinux:rprovides='spl-modules,  spl-dkms,  zfs-modules,  zfs-dkms,  v4l2loopback-modules,  v4l2loopback-dkms, ' 
dh_md5sums -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_builddeb -plinux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-tools-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdocs -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_compress -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_fixperms -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic -X/boot/
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic 
dh_installdeb -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_installdebconf -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
flock -w 60 /home/mike/linux-5.15.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic -- -Vlinux:rprovides='spl-modules,  spl-dkms,  zfs-modules,  zfs-dkms,  v4l2loopback-modules,  v4l2loopback-dkms, ' 
dh_md5sums -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dh_builddeb -plinux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic' in '../linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-113-generic_5.15.0-113.123+test1_amd64.deb'.


So what's going on?

Is this a bug?
Is this intentional and I don't understand the process correctly?
Or am I doing something wrong?


The tutorial I referenced stated:

In order to make your kernel "newer" than the stock Ubuntu kernel from which you are based, you should add a local version modifier. Add
something like "+test1" to the end of the first version number in the
debian.master/changelog file, before building.

My initial understanding was to edit the first line of debian.master/changelog as follows:
linux (5.15.0-113.123+test1) jammy; urgency=medium

However, I think I was placing the local version modifier in the wrong location. When I add it to the end of the ABI number instead of after the upload number, the .deb archive and all packages are named accordingly.
linux (5.15.0-113+test1.123) jammy; urgency=medium


Kernel Naming Scheme
To explain the different parts of the kernel naming scheme the question, What does a specific Ubuntu kernel version number mean?, from Ubuntu wiki explains:

The official version of an Ubuntu kernel tells you a number of things,
including the base upstream version, the current Ubuntu ABI identifier
and the kernel flavour. (See How can we determine the version of the
running kernel? to find your current version number.)
Given a version like 2.6.35-6.9-generic this can be broken into four
parts as below:
<base kernel version>-<ABI number>.<upload number>-<flavour> 

The base kernel version represents the mainline version on which the
Ubuntu kernel is based. The ABI number represents significant changes
in the kernel Application Binary Interface. The upload number is a
monotonically increasing counter for each upload of this base version.
The flavour indicates which kernel configuration variant this is (See
What is a Kernel Flavour?).


Reading the source code
To better understand the process, I read various source code files where the kernel version from debian.master/changelog is read and broken down into various parts and assigned to variables. These are then used to name and build the binary packages.
The first definition to take note of is from debian/debian.env:
DEBIAN=debian.master

Next, the source package name will be the first token from debian.master/changelog. This is defined on line 7 of debian/rules.d/0-common-vars.mk:
src_pkg_name=$(shell sed -n '1s/^\(.*\) (.*).*$$/\1/p' $(DEBIAN)/changelog)

On line 13 of debian/rules.d/0-common-vars.mk:
release := $(shell sed -n '1s/^$(src_pkg_name).*(\(.*\)-.*).*$$/\1/p' $(DEBIAN)/changelog)
revisions := $(shell sed -n 's/^$(src_pkg_name)\ .*($(release)-\(.*\)).*$$/\1/p' $(DEBIAN)/changelog | tac)
revision ?= $(word $(words $(revisions)),$(revisions))

On line 82  of debian/rules.d/0-common-vars.mk:
abinum  := $(shell echo $(revision) | sed -r -e 's/([^\+~]*)\.[^\.]+(~.*)?(\+.*)?$$/\1/')$(abi_suffix)

On line 84 of debian/rules.d/0-common-vars.mk:
abi_release := $(release)-$(abinum)

On line 141 of debian/rules.d/0-common-vars.mk:
bin_pkg_name_unsigned=linux-image-unsinged-$(abi_release)

On line 57 of debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:
bin_pkg_name=$(bin_pkg_name_unsigned)

On line 582 of debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:
binary-%: pkgimg = $(bin_pkg_name)-$*

On line 600 of debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:
$(call dh_all,$(pkgimg))

This line calls dh_all, which is a define directive starting on line 550 of debian/rules.d/2.binary-arch.mk:
define dh_all
    dh_installchangelogs -p$(1)
    dh_installdocs -p$(1)
    dh_compress -p$(1)
    dh_fixperms -p$(1) -X/boot/
    dh_shlibdeps -p$(1) $(shlibdeps_opts)
    dh_installdeb -p$(1)
    dh_installdebconf -p$(1)
    $(lockme) dh_gencontrol -p$(1) -- -Vlinux:rprovides='$(rprovides)'
    dh_md5sums -p$(1)
    dh_builddeb -p$(1)
endef

The last line calls dh_builddeb, which builds the Debian binary package. (See man dh_builddeb for more information.)
Anyway, to see the values of some of these key variables, you can run debian/rules printenv from the kernel source directory:
$ debian/rules printenv | head -n10
dh_testdir
src package name  = linux
series            = jammy
release           = 5.15.0
revisions         = 0.0 9.9 10.10 11.11 12.12 13.13 14.14 15.15 16.16 17.17 18.18 19.19 20.20 21.21 22.22 23.23 24.24 25.25 26.27 27.28 30.31 33.34 34.35 35.36 37.39 39.42 40.43 41.44 43.46 45.48 46.49 47.51 48.54 49.55 50.56 52.58 53.59 56.62 57.63 58.64 59.65 60.66 65.72 66.73 67.74 68.75 69.76 70.77 71.78 72.79 74.81 75.82 76.83 79.86 81.90 83.92 85.95 86.96 88.98 90.100 91.101 93.103 94.104 100.110 102.112 103.113 105.115 106.116 111.121 112.122 113+test1.123
revision          = 113+test1.123
uploadnum         = 113+123
prev_revisions    = 0.0 0.0 9.9 10.10 11.11 12.12 13.13 14.14 15.15 16.16 17.17 18.18 19.19 20.20 21.21 22.22 23.23 24.24 25.25 26.27 27.28 30.31 33.34 34.35 35.36 37.39 39.42 40.43 41.44 43.46 45.48 46.49 47.51 48.54 49.55 50.56 52.58 53.59 56.62 57.63 58.64 59.65 60.66 65.72 66.73 67.74 68.75 69.76 70.77 71.78 72.79 74.81 75.82 76.83 79.86 81.90 83.92 85.95 86.96 88.98 90.100 91.101 93.103 94.104 100.110 102.112 103.113 105.115 106.116 111.121 112.122
prev_revision     = 112.122
abinum            = 113+test1


Final Note
I was unable to find a lot of info regarding this specific topic detailing the addition of a local version modifer. The only source I found that essentially did the same thing I outline here is a GitHub repository, build-ubuntu-kernel. In their build script, the following section modifies the ABI number in debian.master/changelog:
# Examples:
# 6.9.9-060909+customidle-generic
# 6.9.9-060909+customfull-generic
# 6.9.9-060909+customrt-generic
# Note: A hyphen between label and type (e.g. customidle -> custom-idle) causes problems with some parsers
# Because the final version name becomes: 6.9.9-060909+custom-idle-generic, so just keep it combined
echo "*** Updating version in changelog (necessary for Ubuntu)... ✓";
sed -i "s/${KERNEL_SUB_VER}/${KERNEL_SUB_VER}+${KERNEL_VERSION_LABEL}${KERNEL_TYPE}/g" ./debian.master/changelog;

